# Query Optimization (Three Table Join) - Low Query Results, High Query Time

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a query:

```
SELECT last_name, uid, full_name, user_name, email_address, user_photo,
       count(checkin_id) as c_c, max(created_at) as mdi
FROM activity
INNER JOIN users on checkin.user_id = users.uid
INNER JOIN friends on (friends.friend_id = checkin.user_id)
WHERE friends.user_id = '1' and item_id = '2025' and
      created_at >= DATE_SUB('2013-07-10 03:16:24', INTERVAL 30 DAY) and
      venue_id = '5622' and is_approved = 1
GROUP by activity.user_id
ORDER by c_c desc LIMIT 30;
```

The goal of this query, to get all the friends who have done the same activity into the same item as you in the last 30 days.

When I do the explain I get an index_merge on the `checkin` table, for the following indexes:

```
venue_id_2 -> venue_id
item_id -> item_id
```

The query time is:

```
# Query_time: 6.710844  Lock_time: 0.033860 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 16
```

Not sure why something with only 16 rows is taking 6.7 seconds. Any ideas? What should the indexes be here?

Comment: And what is ut_users? They are mentioned in your join conditions, but they aren't listed as tables in the from clause

Comment: Removed them - as it was a mistake.

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by:

"When I do the explain I get an index_merge on the checkin table, for the following indexes:" What is do the explain?

Comment: I ran an "EXPLAIN" on the query.